# Не могу заставить ИЕ отображать шрифт comic sans

Tags: css

Собственно как обычно, ослик не хочет работать, как все нормальные браузеры. На этот раз он не хочет отображать шрифт comic sans. Может кто уже сталкивался? Шрифт задается в стилях:

```
p {
    color: #5b330b;
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

Comment: [Don`t use comic sans](http://www.gliffy.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/should-you-use-comic-sans.jpg)

Comment: Проверил. Все работает. В каких версиях тестируете?

Comment: интернет эксплорер 8

Comment: @Spectre, лучше эта ссылка: http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/typography/104118/

Answer (score 2):

Приведу Вам цитату (хоть и с нескольким опозданием) из книги:

> Больше всего проблем возникает у семейства `fantasy`, т.к. в него попадает любой шрифт, не принадлежащий четырём другим семействам. Сложно представить какие символы будут выводиться на экран. Другое создающее проблемы значение - `cursive`...

и т.д. и т.п. Далее мало интересно, но можно отметить одно - Comic Sans относится как раз к шрифтам `fantasy`. Если Вам абзац выводится курсивом, то получается следующее: браузер не может найти первый шрифт и выводит содержимое шрифтом, семейство которого указано последним.

P.S. а вообще у меня тоже отображается всё. Даже в IE 8...)))